# How to update view model and its dependencies when Checkbox selected in Knockout.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

Currently I have a very large of data model that is presented to the user with multiple options and events.

1. List item as checkboxes
2. Update the object's datetime when checked
3. Add checked item data to table array
4. Two options to deselect items: remove button on table or uncheck input
5. Post update to server when item is selected or deselected

I have been unable to create the correct knockoutjs script to make all events possible.
I definitely need help.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/likwidmack/BxZGr/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have refactored your code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/SKnMg/3/

Comment: Very nice. I hadn't leveraged the event binding before.